# Category wise count in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

Data in MongoDB Collection is:

```
{ type : "bike", name : "honda" },
{ type : "car", name : "Audi } ,
{ type : "truck", name : "mercedes"},
{ type : "bike", name : "suzuki" },
{ type : "bike", name : "yamaha" },
{ type : "car", name : "tesla"}
```

I want the output as :

```
{ bike : 3 },
{ car : 2 },
{ truck : 1}
```

I am not able to do this by reading documentation. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` by type and get sum of duplicates,
- `$arrayToObject` convert k and v format array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [{ k: "$_id", v: "$count" }]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]).toArray();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I4sselfPttc)

Comment: It is giving output as some set of objects starting with Aggregation Server.

Comment: actually you have provided the result in your question is set of objects, can you verify it?

Comment: actually I got it, aggregation returns the cursor, to get the data we need to append .toArray() method. Thanks for the help.